# JavaScript or JSON to customize SharePoint Calendar?

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-calendar, calendar-view

I have a user who does not want the times to display in their SharePoint calendar. When I change the column settings to "Date only", it defaults to "12:00 am - 12:00 am". I created a content type and removed the date fields and it still defaulted to "12:00 am - 12:00 am".

Is there a way I can use some code in the column formatting to hide the times and only show the title?

Comment: Are you using [modern experience calendar view](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/14/create-a-modern-calendar-view-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/) in list or classic experience calendar list?

Comment: Modern experience, forced into classic experience in order to get the calendar. Otherwise, the calendar will render as a list.

Comment: You can create modern calender views as well in the list. Check link in my above comment. You cannot apply JSON formatting in classic experience. Also, modern experience calendar supports JSON formatting but very limited functionalities currently. Not possible to achieve what you are looking for using JSON formatting.